# Confused on creating a json dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a JSON from the data returned by DynamoDB. and I'm confused on how to create it.

Currently, I get data into an array and populate the JSON below is my code.

```
var res = {};

dynamodb.scan(params).promise().then(function (data) {
    var ingred = data.Items[0].ingredients;
    res = {
        [ingred]: {}
    };
    ingred.max = Math.max(...data.Items.map(({max}) => parseFloat(max))) + "";
    ingred.min = Math.min(...data.Items.map(({min}) => parseFloat(min))) + "";

    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));

})
```

Here when I run this, I get the output as below.

```
{
    "a": {}
}
{
    "b": {}
}
{
    "c": {}
}
```

and when I change my code to the below

```
var res = {};

        dynamodb.scan(params).promise().then(function (data) {
            var ingred = data.Items[0].ingredients;
        console.log(ingred);
            ingred = {};
            ingred.max = Math.max(...data.Items.map(({ max }) => parseFloat(max))) + "";
            ingred.min = Math.min(...data.Items.map(({ min }) => parseFloat(min))) + "";

            console.log(JSON.stringify(ingred, null, 4));

        })
```

the output I get is as below

```
a
{
    "max": "14",
    "min": "8.5"
}
b
{
    "max": "1.98",
    "min": "0.37"
}
c
{
    "max": "155",
    "min": "6"
}
```

I am trying to achieve the result as below.

```
{
    "a": {
        "max": "14",
        "min": "8.5"
    },
    "b": {
        "max": "1.98",
        "min": "0.37"
    },
    "c": {
        "max": "155",
        "min": "6"
    }
}
```

please let me know on how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: A clear sample of the data in `data.Items[0]` and another sample for the expected output will help people answer this question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `ingred` in the `res`

```
var res = {};
dynamodb.scan(params).promise().then(function (data) {
        var ingred = data.Items[0].ingredients;
        res[ ingred ] = {};
        res[ ingred ].max = Math.max(...data.Items.map(({ max }) => parseFloat(max))) + "";
        res[ ingred ].min = Math.min(...data.Items.map(({ min }) => parseFloat(min))) + "";
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
var res = {};
dynamodb.scan(params).promise().then(function (data) {

  var ingred = data.Items[0].ingredients;
  res[ingred] = {};

  res[ingred].max = Math.max(...data.Items.map(({ max }) => parseFloat(max))) + "";
  res[ingred].min = Math.min(...data.Items.map(({ min }) => parseFloat(min))) + "";

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `max` and `min` to your object in `res[ingred]`.

```
var res = {};
dynamodb.scan(params).promise().then(function (data) {
    var ingred = data.Items[0].ingredients;
    res[ingred] = {};
    res[ingred].max = Math.max(...data.Items.map(({ max }) => parseFloat(max))) + "";
    res[ingred].min = Math.min(...data.Items.map(({ min }) => parseFloat(min))) + "";
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store a and b into an object and store that into a global object:

```
  const result = {};

  dynamodb.scan(params).promise().then(function (data){
     const ingred = data.Items[0].ingredients;
     result[ingred] = {
       max: Math.max(...data.Items.map(({ max }) => parseFloat(max))),
       min: Math.min(...data.Items.map(({ min }) => parseFloat(min))),
     };
  })
```